# How to overwrite: catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml with XML Magento

Tags: xml, magento, overwrite, php

I have a simple module and I want to overwrite some templates files.

For instance, when I want to overwrite view.phtml via XML I open up my module layout XML file and just add:

```
<catalog_product_view>
  <reference name="product.info">
    <action method="setTemplate">
      <template>my-module-template-folder/catalog/product/view.phtml</template>
    </action>
  </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

But I also want to overwrite: catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml and I have tried anything but nothing works. My (to bad way to easy) thought was just to add another `<action method="setTemplate">` for the new file but nothing offcourse.

Can someone please provide me the right code?

Answer (score 2):

Either you put a copy of `catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml` into your design override under `app/design/frontend/default/<yourdesign>/template/`.
Or you can use **unset** in your layout XML at first before **redefining** the block you are setting the template for again.

Take a look at `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/catalog.xml:268`

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_simple translate="label" module="catalog">
    <label>Catalog Product View (Simple)</label>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="catalog/product_view_type_simple" name="product.info.simple" as="product_type_data" template="catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.simple.extra" as="product_type_data_extra" translate="label">
                <label>Product Extra Info</label>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>
```

You might want to reference `product.info.simple` within `PRODUCT_TYPE_simple`.

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <!-- <action method="unsetChild"><name>product.info.simple</name></action> -->
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <!-- app/design/frondend/default/<yourdesign>/template/my-module-template-folder/catalog/product/view.phtml -->
            <template>my-module-template-folder/catalog/product/view.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>
```

**EDITED AFTER REPLY:**

Thanks for your reply. Just to share the outcome that works:

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>
    <reference name="product.info.simple">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>my-modus-template-folder/catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>
```

Comment: @user1897753 it was better if you had edited your own question instead.